# Vertical space before an environment only when preceded by text

Tags: spacing

I need to place a user defined environment within another environment, either alone or after some text, and I want that a vertical space is *automatically* insterted only in the latter case. In other words, I want to define `environment2` so that there's some vertical space before it in this case

```
\begin{environment}
Text
      <--- space here
\begin{environment2}
Text
\end{environment2}
\end{environment}
```

but *not* in this case:

```
\begin{environment}
\begin{environment2}
Text
\end{environment2}
\end{environment}
```

Comment: Of course, you are using the `environment` environment only between paragraphs. aren’t you?

Comment: Yes, of course. In fact, my environment defines a marginal note through `wrapfigure`

Answer (score 2):

The typical technique for addressing this kind of problem is to use the `\everypar` hook, which gets executed every time TeX *begins* a new paragraph.  So you can have a switch, say `\if@EnvOneHasText@`, which you set to `false` when you begin the outer environment, while adding to the `\everypar` hook an instruction that sets the same switch to `true`.  Then you test this switch at the beginning of the inner environment:

- if you find that it is still false, then you know that TeX didn’t
  begin any paragraph since the outermost environment has begun, so
  you do *not* add the vertical space;
- if, on the other hand, you find that it has become true, you know
  that TeX found some text between the beginning of the outer
  environment and the beginning of the inner one, that forced it
  to start a new paragrph, so you *do* add the vertical space.

Here’s a MWE that illustrates this technique:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\if@EnvOneHasText@{\newif\if@EnvOneHasText@}

\newenvironment*{environment1}{%
    \par % make sure we terminate any preceding paragraph
    % The following is just to mark where the environment begins;
    % you should substitute your real code here:
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
    \noindent Begin of \texttt{environment1}.\par
    % The following two lines do the trick:
    \@EnvOneHasText@false
    \everypar \expandafter{\the\everypar \@EnvOneHasText@true}%
}{%
    \par
    % Add whatever you need here.
    \noindent End of \texttt{environment1}.\par
    \addvspace{\bigskipamount}% for example
}

\newenvironment*{environment2}{%
    \par
    \if@EnvOneHasText@
        \addvspace{\bigskipamount}% say
    \fi
    % The following is just to mark where the environment begins;
    % you should substitute your real code here:
    \noindent
    Begin of \texttt{environment2}.\par
}{
    \par
    % Add whatever you need here.
    \noindent End of \texttt{environment2}.\par
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Some text to begin with.

\begin{environment1}
    \begin{environment2}
        Some text inside the innermost environment.
    \end{environment2}
\end{environment1}

Words words words words\ldots

\begin{environment1}
    Some text in between.
    \begin{environment2}
        Some text inside the innermost environment.
    \end{environment2}
\end{environment1}

Words words words words\ldots

\begin{environment1}
    Does it nest correctly?
    \begin{environment2}
        Some text inside the outer \texttt{environment2} environment.
        \begin{environment1}
            \begin{environment2}
                Some text inside the inner \texttt{environment2} environment.
                There should be no space above this text.
            \end{environment2}
            We are now inside the inner \texttt{environment1} environment.
        \end{environment1}
    \end{environment2}
\end{environment1}

\end{document}
```