# Add vspace only if immediately preceded by paragraph / if not at the beginning of a proof

Tags: positioning, paragraphs, thmtools, parskip

My question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402382/vertical-space-before-an-environment-only-when-preceded-by-text), however my situation is more specific and I'm wondering whether there isn't a simpler (and more performant) solution than executing code for *every* paragraph:

I wrote a small macro to structure lengthy proofs and highlight key steps, called `\proofpart`. To set apart the step in question from the preceding step of the proof it uses `\noindent` and, before, adds some `\vspace`. Now the problem arises when I use it at the very beginning of a proof: In this case `\vspace` influences the positioning of my entire proof and increases its top margin. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcommand{\proofpart}[1]{%
  \vspace{0.7em}%
  \noindent%
  \textsc{#1}%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=2em,
  spacebelow=2em,
  postheadspace=1em,
  headfont=\upshape\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{mytheoremstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=-1em, % <-- reduce margin, so that it is clear that the
  % proof belongs to the previous theorem/lemma/…
  %
  spacebelow=2em,
  postheadspace=1em,
  % headfont=\itshape,
  headfont=\upshape\bfseries,
  bodyfont = \normalfont,
  qed=$\qedsymbol$,
  headpunct={:},
]{myproofstyle}

\newcounter{mathcounter}
\numberwithin{mathcounter}{chapter}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem},
  style=mytheoremstyle,
  numberlike=mathcounter
]{theorem}

% Remove amsthm's proof environment, so that we can override it below.
\let\proof\undefined
\let\endproof\undefined

\declaretheorem[
  name={Proof},
  style=myproofstyle,
  numbered=no
]{proof}


\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Some preliminary remarks.

  \proofpart{Step 1:} % <-- No problem here
    Foo

  \proofpart{Step 2:} % <-- No problem here
    Bar
\end{proof}


\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \proofpart{Step 1:} % <-- This will increase spacing between theorem and proof
    Foo

  \proofpart{Step 2:} % <-- No problem here
    Bar
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I make use of the fact that token list `\everypar` is non-empty at the beginning of `trivlist` environment when the first paragraph is not yet stated, and after the beginning of first paragraph. Since all theorem environments internally use `trivlist`, I use it to test whether we are at the beginning of `proof` environment.

```
\newcommand{\proofpart}[1]{%
  % store contents of \everypar in \@tempa
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\the\everypar}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    % if \@tempa is empty, insert vspace
    \vspace{.7em}%
  \else
    % otherwise, reconstruct \everypar
    \everypar\expandafter{\@tempa}%
  \fi
  \noindent
  \textsc{#1}%
}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\proofpart}[1]{%
  % token list \everypar is non-empty at the beginning of proof env 
  % (inherited from trivlist env)
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\the\everypar}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \vspace{.7em}%
  \else
    \everypar\expandafter{\@tempa}%
  \fi
  \noindent
  \textsc{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=2em,
  spacebelow=2em,
  postheadspace=1em,
  headfont=\upshape\bfseries,
  notefont=\mdseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{mytheoremstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=-1em, % <-- reduce margin, so that it is clear that the
  % proof belongs to the previous theorem/lemma/…
  %
  spacebelow=2em,
  postheadspace=1em,
  % headfont=\itshape,
  headfont=\upshape\bfseries,
  bodyfont = \normalfont,
  qed=$\qedsymbol$,
  headpunct={:},
]{myproofstyle}

\newcounter{mathcounter}
\numberwithin{mathcounter}{chapter}

\declaretheorem[
  name={Theorem},
  style=mytheoremstyle,
  numberlike=mathcounter
]{theorem}

% Remove amsthm's proof environment, so that we can override it below.
\let\proof\undefined
\let\endproof\undefined

\declaretheorem[
  name={Proof},
  style=myproofstyle,
  numbered=no
]{proof}


\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Some preliminary remarks.

  \proofpart{Step 1:} % <-- No problem here
    Foo

  \proofpart{Step 2:} % <-- No problem here
    Bar
\end{proof}


\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}\showthe\everypar
  \proofpart{Step 1:} % <-- This will increase spacing between theorem and proof
    Foo

  \proofpart{Step 2:} % <-- No problem here
    Bar
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]